# Find and files of same name only in directory below and copy to a different directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

This script is finding the correct file but it is also searching through other directories and copying them. How can I find only the specific files, rename to data.log_$1 and cp in new directory.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Data.log -exec cp -rfp {} / extracted/ \;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a stray slash there: `cp -rfp {} / extracted/` should probably be `cp -rfp {} extracted/` (or maybe `cp -rfp {} /extracted/`)